# Can I disable the hover menu on a window's green maximize button?

Tags: window-manager

I just updated my macOS to 10.15.7.  I notice that now when I hover over the window's green maximize button for about a second it now presents me with a menu, which I have to click to dismiss.  Is there any way to change this behavior so it no longer automatically displays a menu when I happen to hover over the maximize button for too long?  I suspect it will get in my way far more often than it will be useful to me.

The menu has four options when I view it on my secondary display:

- Enter Full Screen
- Tile Window to Left of Screen
- Tile Window to Right of Screen
- Move to Built-in Retina Display

[image: Maximize button hover menu]

Comment: As a side note: what's the official name for the green button? A cursory Google search didn't provide me with any definitive answers.

Comment: Thank you for documenting this! It’s called the maximize button. https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=1161855204

Comment: @bmike Thanks! I see the term defined in that book, and I've updated the terminology in my answer accordingly.

Comment: @bmike Huh, I could have sworn I read it was called the Zoom button! I wonder, I've mainly looked at older docs, do you know if the name changed?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy — It's listed under both in the linked [Apple Style Guide](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=1161855204). "**maximize button** — The rightmost (green) button of the three window controls at the lft of the title bar. Users click this button to go full screen, or Option-click it to _maximize_ the window". "**zoom button** — The rightmost button of the three window controls at the left of the title bar."

Comment: So we have a maximum zoom button?!?!! I am here for this content @Wowfunhappy

Comment: A year and a half later, and I've forgotten this is even a part of the UI, so I guess it hasn't gotten in my way as much as I've predicted.  On the other hand, I literally never use it, so it's also not helpful to me.